# How update data in JavaScript when flask send a josinify response

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, raspberry-pi

I am making a project with raspberry Pi, is a control and monitoring data through internet.
Finally I can make the communication with flask-html-JavaScript
In summary I want to update my chart js graph when the flask function response with jsonify data
I am using Ajax method with getjson but I am executing with setinterval and I don’t want to use setinterval, I want that the getjson function execute when flask function response with jsonify data

Exist any method that can make it?

this is my code in flask:

```
@app.route('/start', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start():
n = request.form['number']
print(int(n))
for i in range(int(n)):
    GPIO.output(19, GPIO.LOW)
    while gt.read_sensor() == 0:
        pass
    now0 = datetime.now()
    for j in range(1):
        value = adc.read( channel = 0 )
        volt = (value/1023)*3.3
        presure = ((volt/3.3)-0.1)*3/2
        p1.append(presure)
        global pon
        pon = presure
        time.sleep(0.25)
        pon = -100
```

Here I capture the value sensor and I call update with global variable the function presson:

```
@app.route('/pon')
def presson():

return jsonify(result = presson)
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
var pon = 0;
    var test = 0;
    function sendData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url_for('start') }}",
            data: { number : $('#number').val() }
            });
         
        setInterval(update_values,100);
            }
    function update_values() {
            $.getJSON('/pon',
            function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data.result);
                pon = data.result;
                console.log(data)
                                    
            });
```

currently that work good, but sometimes the value is not update, then I want that the function getJSON() run only when recieve a correct value (without setInterval method), what recommend me?

Comment: What code do you have so far? Have you looked into async/await (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: already add the code, can you help me? :c